# SELECT From Multiple tables with many to many relations

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hello everyone I have inherirted a poorly designed database and I need to get some information from 3 tables

**Franchise**

```
  Id(Int, PK)
  FrID (varchar(50))
  FirstName (varchar(50))
  LastName (varchar(50))
```

**Store**

```
 Id (Int, PK) 
 FrID (varchar(50))
 StoreNumber (varchar(50))
 StoreName 
 Address
```

**Pricing**

```
 Id (int, PK)
 StoreNumber  (varchar(50))
 Price1
 Price2
 Price3
```

and the data

```
ID, FrID ,FirstName,LastName   
 1, 10   ,John Q    , TestCase  
 2, 10   ,Jack Q    , TestCase  
 3, 11   ,Jack Q    , TestCase


ID, FrID, StoreNumber , StoreName , Address 
10, 10  , 22222       , TestStore1, 123 Main street 
11, 10  , 33333       , TestStore2, 144 Last Street
12, 10  , 44444       , TestStore2, 145 Next Street
13, 11  , 55555       , Other Test, 156 Other st


ID, StoreNumber, Price1, Price2, Price3 
1,  22222      ,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99 
2,  33333      ,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99 
3,  44444      ,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99 
4,  55555      ,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99
```

Here is what I have done

```
 SELECT F.FirstName,F.LastName,F.FrID , S.StoreNumber,S.StoreName,S.Address,
        P.Price1,P.Price2,P.Price3
 FROM Franchisee F 
 JOIN Store S on F.FrID = S.FrID 
 JOIN Pricing P on P.StoreNumber = S.StoreNumber
```

This part works, but I end up with lots of duplicates, For example Jack Q gets listed for his store plus every store that John Q is on. Is there anyway to fix this with out a database redesign.

Comment: but john and jack both belong to the `10` franchise id.. so their stores seem to be common.

Comment: Give us a sample of the data you expect to get back. The way your data is structured currently a single query is going to produce duplicates.

Comment: @Gaby , Thanks for the edit I noticed and tried to fix it, but you beat me to it.

Comment: I found out what happened, I still dont know how to get around it, it looks like this DB used to be a very wide and ugly excel spread sheet, someone tried to split it up. On the spread sheet, Jack is listed only once as Fr ID 10 and along with one store address where is john is listed many times. I am not sure what else to do here but to recommend they hire a db person to fix this.

Comment: The question then is why does Jack Q exist in the DB with FrID 10 and 11 if (as you say) he's only on the spreadsheet once? Sounds like the conversion to tables was messed up and so your data is invalid/corrupt. You should fix the export/convert process first, then once you have valid data you can worry about how to query it.

Comment: No, he is listed on the spread sheet that way as well, I guess they co own some stores and then he owns his own stores as well so on the spread sheet he is listed with 10 and 11.

Comment: Okay, what I thought was duplicate data is some type of owners list (co-ownership).  You will have duplicates in the results unless you combine them.  See my second solution that combines the owners names into one.

Comment: So it seems you have a `FrID` that can have many `Franchisee` records and many `Store` records (many-to-many), and your `Store` has a one-to-many join to `Pricing`. Any attempt to represent this in a single table will be ugly, @CRAFTYDBA has provided a possible solution that essentially creates a CSV field for `Franchisee` information, but showing these 3 levels of information in one table really doesn't seem useful.

Comment: @TimothyWalters I agree that it is not very useful, but what I was asked to create was a CSV. I hope they get this mess figured out cause it was a hot potato that fell in my lap

Comment: @Ksliman I know there's no instance of it in your sample data provided, but are there cases where one `Store` has multiple `Pricing` rows? If not then the relationship is easier (`Pricing` is then just an extension table, not a one-to-many relationship), but if so it gets a bit messier.

Comment: @TimothyWalters No Each store only has one Pricing Row. Someone else told me to make a look up table for each of the storeIDs and Franchise IDs, but I did not know where to go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there is a whole laundry list of issues such as character fields such as [FrId] being used as strings, reserved words such as [address] being used as name, etc.

Let's put the bad design issues aside.

First, I need to create a quick test environment.  I did not put in Foreign Keys since that constraint is not needed to get the correct answer.

```
--
-- Setup test tables
--


-- Just playing
use Tempdb;
go

-- drop table
if object_id('franchise')>  0
drop table franchise;
go

-- create table
create table franchise
( 
  Id int primary key,
  FrID varchar(50),
  FirstName varchar(50),
  LastName varchar(50)
);

-- insert data
insert into franchise values
( 1, 10, 'John Q', 'TestCase'),  
( 2, 10, 'Jack Q', 'TestCase'),
( 3, 11, 'Jack Q', 'TestCase');

-- select data
select * from franchise;
go


-- drop table
if object_id('store')>  0
drop table store;
go

-- create table
create table store
( 
  Id int primary key,
  FrID varchar(50),
  StoreNumber varchar(50),
  StoreName varchar(50),
  Address varchar(50)
);

-- insert data
insert into store values
(10, 10, 22222, 'TestStore1', '123 Main street'),
(11, 10, 33333, 'TestStore2', '144 Last Street'),
(12, 10, 44444, 'TestStore2', '145 Next Street'),
(13, 11, 55555, 'Other Test', '156 Other Street');

-- select data
select * from store;
go


-- drop table
if object_id('pricing')>  0
drop table pricing;
go

-- create table
create table pricing
( 
  Id int primary key,
  StoreNumber varchar(50),
  Price1 money,
  Price2 money,
  Price3 money
);


-- insert data
insert into pricing values
(1,  22222,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99),
(2,  33333,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99), 
(3,  44444,  19.99, 20.99 , 30.99), 
(4,  55555,  19.95, 20.95 , 30.95);

-- select data
select * from pricing;
go
```

The **main issue** is that the franchise table should have the primary key (PK) on FrId, not Id.  I do not understand why there are duplicates.

However, the query below removes them by grouping.  I changed the pricing data for Jack Q to show it is a different record.

```
--
-- Fixed Query - Version 1
--

select 
  f.FirstName, 
  f.LastName, 
  f.FrID, 
  s.StoreNumber, 
  s.StoreName, 
  s.Address,
  p.Price1,
  p.Price2, 
  p.Price3
from

-- Remove duplicates from francise
(
select 
  LastName,
  FirstName,
  Max(FrID) as FrID
from
  franchise
group by
  LastName,
  FirstName
) as f

join store s on f.FrID = s.FrID 
join pricing p on p.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber;
```

The correct output is below.

[image]

If I am correct, remove the duplicates entries and change the primary key.

**Change Requirements**

Okay, you are placing two or more owners in the same table.

Below uses a sub query to combine the owners list into one string.  Another way is to have a flag called primary owner.  Choose that as the display name.

```
--
-- Fixed Query - Version 2
--

select 
  f.OwnersList,
  f.FrID, 
  s.StoreNumber, 
  s.StoreName, 
  s.Address,
  p.Price1,
  p.Price2, 
  p.Price3
from

-- Compose owners list
(
  select 
  FrID, 
  (
    SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName + ';'
    FROM franchise as inner1
    WHERE inner1.FrID = outer1.FrID
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ) as OwnersList
  from franchise as outer1
  group by FrID
) as f (FrId, OwnersList)
join store s on f.FrID = s.FrID 
join pricing p on p.StoreNumber = s.StoreNumber
```

Here is the output from the second query.

[image]

Comment: Thanks this was what I needed, I will be recommending that this db be redesigned and for god sake hire a dba :-)

Comment: This is even better, how ever Jack Q under FRID 10 only co-owns one stores 44444, so listing him as co-owner of the others would be incorrect. Ideally I would like to list John Q for all his stores then John Q for store 44444 and then Jack Q for store 44444 and then Store 55555, Is that even possible?

Comment: But that relationship is not stored in the database model.  You have John Q and Jack Q related to Franchise 10.  You have to change the data model to reflect this relationship.  Remove FrID from table franchise.  Create a ownership table that has the following (franchise id, FrId, store id).  Now you can detail the ownership.